# How to set height on UICollectionView / keep height of UICollectionView from expanding in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Using: Xcode 10.1 beta, Swift 4.2

I am using auto-layout to position a UICollectionView among other elements in Storyboard. Right above and below the UICollectionView are two 'views' that are 1 (pt? px? not sure of the unit of measurement) tall, used kinda like 'horizontal rules'. When I open the app on the iPhone 8 simulator everything is spaced as I hoped it would be. When I open the app on the iPhone XR simulator the bottom 'view' is stretched to about a 100 (px, pt) high. I am trying to have the UICollection view stay between the two 1pt 'views' on any screen size.

[iPhone 8 UICollectionView between 1px 'views' spaced correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cZkJ.png)
[iPhone XR with bottom 'view' stretched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmSPU.png)

I tried setting a constraint on the height of the UICollectionView and I get this error:

> the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.

The cell or 'item' is set to 60 for both width and height. I have tried even smaller than that in case there are insets that I just cannot see. The current insets are all set to 0 as well.

Below is the current code I have for the UICollectionView in my ViewController:

```
    extension ProfileViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.gameImages.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "testCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCell
    print("Here is the cell: \(cell)")
    if self.gameImages.count > 0 {
      cell.testImage.image = self.gameImages[0].image
    }
    cell.testImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 76, height: 76)
    cell.testImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.testImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.testImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.testImage.frame.height/2
    cell.testImage.clipsToBounds = true
    return cell
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                      sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: 76, height: 76)
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                      minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
//    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 20.0,
//                        left: 20.0,
//                        bottom: 20.0,
//                        right: 20.0)
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0,
                        left: 0.0,
                        bottom: 0.0,
                        right: 0.0)
//    return 0
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                      minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

//    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 20.0,
//                        left: 20.0,
//                        bottom: 20.0,
//                        right: 20.0).left
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0,
                        left: 0.0,
                        bottom: 0.0,
                        right: 0.0).left
//    return 0
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                      insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
//    return 0
  }

}


class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

  var gameImages: [UIImageView] = []

  private let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20.0,
                                           left: 20.0,
                                           bottom: 20.0,
                                           right: 20.0)

  @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var fullNameLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var chatButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var emailButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var editProfileButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var memberSinceLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var myGamesLabel: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
  profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
  profileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
  profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.height/2
  profileImage.clipsToBounds = true

  // Set calender image inside memberSince label
  let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
  imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "calenderIcon")
  let imageOffsetY: CGFloat = -(imageAttachment.image!.size.height - (self.memberSinceLabel.font?.pointSize)!) / 2.90 // -5.0
  imageAttachment.bounds = CGRect(x: -5, y: imageOffsetY, width: imageAttachment.image!.size.width / 1.5, height: imageAttachment.image!.size.height / 1.5)
  let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
  let completeText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
  completeText.append(attachmentString)

  let textAfterIcon = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Since " + (MainTabController.user?.memberSince)!)
  completeText.append(textAfterIcon)
  self.memberSinceLabel.textAlignment = .center
  self.memberSinceLabel.attributedText = completeText

  usernameLabel.text = MainTabController.user?.username
  fullNameLabel.text = MainTabController.user?.name
  descriptionLabel.text = MainTabController.user?.description

  var games = MainTabController.user?.myGames

  // Get images from User's object gameImages URL
  if let gamesCount = games?.count {
    for index in 0..<gamesCount {

      let imageName = "image" + String(index)
      let url = URL(string: (MainTabController.user?.myGames[index].imageURL)!)
      downloadImage(from: url!) { (image) in
        var imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        self.gameImages.append(imageView)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
      }
    }
  }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "logout" {
        CommonUtils.clearAuthToken()
    }
}

@IBAction func logout(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "logout", sender: self)
}

  func getData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: completion).resume()
  }

  func downloadImage(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
    getData(from: url) { data, response, error in
      guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
      print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)
      DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        completion(UIImage(data: data)!)
      }
    }
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue (visually) by removing all the constraints, changing the 'phone' template in Storyboard to the iPhone XR, and reseting the constraints with auto-layout. 
However, this did not remove the error:

> the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.